# Qt - Change application title dynamically on macOS

Tags: c++, qt

I want to change the title of my **Qt 5.15.0** application after it was executed.

For doing that, I'm using the [setWindowTitle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop) function of the QWidget class, like so:

```
setWindowTitle("My new window title");
```

Turns out the title is changed correctly on Windows but not on macOS. Here are the results:

**Windows 10**

[image: Windows result]

**macOS Catalina**

[image: macOS result]

You can see that in macOS the title is updated in the Window but not in the MenuBar (top) and in the Dock (bottom).

Is there a way to change all the titles on macOS once the app is running?

---

### Edit

I managed to change the MenuBar title using the Objective-C code posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66358824/how-to-rename-the-program-name-menu-label-in-a-macos-x-program) (I just had to rename my .cpp file to .mm):

```
#import <AppKit/NSApplication.h>
#import <AppKit/NSMenu.h>

void setMenuProgramName(const char* newName)
{
    NSMenu* mainMenu = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainMenu];
    NSMenu* appMenu = [[mainMenu itemAtIndex:0] submenu];
    [appMenu setTitle:[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:newName]];
}
```

There's still the problem with changing the name in the Dock. There are some insights [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808226/changing-cocoa-app-icon-title-and-menu-labels-at-runtime) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708207/loading-main-window-at-applicationdidfinishlaunching-in-cocoa-application/22852668#22852668) but I couldn't make it work yet. It is said that I should "comment out NSApplicationMain in supporting files -> main.m" but I don't have that file and I don't know how could I do that using Qt. That's why I propose that the question be reopened since there's no solution for that yet.

---

### Edit II

Apparently, as mentioned in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312695/change-dock-title-programmatically/26452198#26452198), there's no way to change the title when you hover over the app icon in the Dock.

Alternatively, you can add a "badge" with the following code, but that's meant for notifications.

```
[[NSApp dockTile] setBadgeLabel:@"My custom text"]
```

It would be nice to know why this can't be changed - if it's because of a bad design decision or just a poorly developed framework.

Answer (score 0):

you can like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QString windowTitle("New Title");
    this->setWindowTitle(windowTitle); 
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing but it doesn't change the title in the Dock and in the MenuBar. That's the whole point of the question.